# Connecting Opensearch with MySQL - MySQL Data Source for Opensearch Indexes

Tags: mysql, solr, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

I need to establish a connection between Opensearch and a data source like MySQL to enable the recreation of indexes in Opensearch using SQL queries to a database, similar to how SOLR does it.

Is it feasible to accomplish this task? Currently, I'm unable to find information that sheds light on this topic, and my understanding is that this functionality might not be viable.

Tx!